# Qual a melhor forma de separar as duas listas em C# fazendo uma operação com cada lado do split

Tags: c#

Esse questionamento veio a minha cabeça em uma atividade que estava fazendo aqui no trabalho.

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer esta operação?

O exemplo que trago seria digamos que temos um objeto T, e temos uma List, se eu operar por exemplo:

```
objeto.Where(o => o.Data < DateTime.Now).ForEach(o => fazX());
```

Teríamos nesse caso logicamente 2 listas, mas em código nós temos 1 só, se eu quisesse operar a outra parte eu teria de fazer outro where desta forma:

```
objeto.Where(o => o.Data > DateTime.Now).ForEach(o =>fazY());
```

Dessa forma se opera as duas partes da lista com funções diferentes, porém eu queria saber se existe uma forma de fazer tudo isto somente em 1 linha, acredito que seja possível já que me parece um problema simples e comum, só não consegui encontrar por aqui nem em outro lugar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usando {} você pode criar um escopo dentro da função lambda, e lá dentro colocar um If

```
lista.ForEach(x=>  { if (x == "") FazX(); else FazY();});
```

No seu caso:

```
objeto.ForEach(o => { if (o.Data > DateTime.Now) fazY(); else fazX();});
```

ps. Acho que quebrando a linha fica mais legível.

Comment: Hum, não pensei nessa possibilidade, acreditei que teria algo + elegante com Linq ou algo do tipo, mas gostei dessa solução também.

Answer (score 1):

A solução do Rovann funciona perfeitamente para o seu cenário, além do LINQ deixar "mais bonito" o código.
Porém utilizar o `.ForEach` do LINQ é muito mais lento do que utilizar o `foreach` convencional, que por sua vez, na maioria dos casos (não é sempre, então convém testar sempre) é mais lento que o `for`.

Sugiro utilizar o loop for para seu cenário e otimizar a performance do seu sistema.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
{
     if (lista[i].Data > DateTime.Now)
         FazY();
     else
         FazX();
 }
```

Comment: A minha questão tinha realmente menos a ver com performance e mais com se existia um modo "ala javascript" de escrever o forEach...
E o LINQ realmente se aproxima do que eu esperava, mas sim, a performance para mim neste caso era bem importante tanto é que minha solução foi idêntica a sua pois precisava dessa velocidade na operação em questão.